# Why is body background image not showing?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have simple code with a text inside body tag for html and one css stylesheet just to have a background image, and I am not sure why background image doesn't show up at all.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    Test    
</body>

</html>
```

and the CSS is just this :

```
#body { 
    background-image: url(images/ninja.jpg);
}
```

I have `"ninja.jpg"` inside the images folder. and still background image doesn't show up. I have tried putting `images/ninja.jpg` within quotes as well(ie: `"images/ninja.jpg"`) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the `#` from your CSS rule

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `#body`
Use `body`
try

```
body { background-image: url(images/ninja.jpg); }
```

for css
 #body refers to the element with attribute `id="body"`

```css
body {background-color: green;} /*this is the actual body*/

#body{background-color: red;} /*this is the paragraph*/
```

```html
This is green

<p id="body">This is red</p>
```

Comment: What's the difference between # and not? I know this but op doesn't lets educate him/her.

Comment: # is used if you add an id

Comment: eg: <p id="body"></p>

Comment: @MarkPerera Good. 1 up

Answer (score 1):

no # required to html tag selectors:

```
 body { background-image: url(images/ninja.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a # hash it not needed until you are work with element id for css

Just remove # and it work.

```
body { 
    background-image: url(images/ninja.jpg); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

body is not an ID...we use # for only id selectors, 
body is just a tag,
so you can simply use below...it works fine

> body { background-image: url(images/ninja.jpg); }